# Adjusting bottom margin

Tags: spacing, margins

I added the preamble:

```
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=3cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
```

But it produces weird spacings like this:

[image]

It seems the problem occurs because the bottom margin is forced to be *exactly* `2cm`. So, is it possible to specify the bottom margin to be *at least* `2cm`?

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on what surrounds the equation, which includes what follows it on the following page. The reason here is that LaTeX inserts some stretch between document components in an attempt to optimize the layout, possibly resulting in the display you see.

Using `\raggedbottom` might fix this, or issuing a manual page break. But leave such manual intervention to end of your typesetting adventure...